# How do I compare contents of folder, files?

Tags: windows, merge, comparison

Is there a way to natively compare files and folders for content, perhaps in command prompt?  If not, is there a good program for that?

I've heard of [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/), is it any good?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Natively, you can use the `comp` or the `fc` commands.

[comp](http://ss64.com/nt/comp.html)
[fc](http://ss64.com/nt/fc.html)

Comment: FC is what I was looking for

Answer (score 4):

[As mentioned before](https://superuser.com/questions/56603/what-is-a-good-text-comparison-tool-for-windows), WinMerge is a good program - as are a handful of other options.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/).

- It can compare directories against each other, regardless whether the directory is local or FTP.
- It can sync those directories, including subdirectories, with custom include/exclude file patterns.
- It can compare files against each other. There are free plugins for Office documents, images, you name it.

I know the question has long been answered, but thought this might still be helpful for later readers.

Comment: thanks for that, i was looking for a native way to do it but its great to know this software exists!

Answer (score 0):

[SourceGear DiffMerge](http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/) compares files and folders, and is free to use.